# Can I use 'of' with a geographical name?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

How should I use *of* with a geographical name, like

> ...top rated hair clinic of uk.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Of* with a superlative usually takes a **group** of individuals as its object; it's more or less equivalent to *among*:

> She is the best **of** this year's students.
>
> It is the top-rated hair clinic **of** those we surveyed.

With a location or collective we usually use *in*:

> She is the best student **in** this year's class.
>
> It is the top-rated hair clinic **in** the UK.

But where location or membership in a collective employs a different preposition, we use that one:

> She is the best student **at** Cambridge. (... *because the students who are being compared are restricted to those **at** Cambridge*)
>
> It is the top-rated hair clinic **on** High Street. (... *because the clinics being compared are restricted to those **on** High Street*)